# Using same validation from 2 places with a tweak in one of them

Tags: design

I'm calling a validation function from 2 places in my code, which perform a series of validations on the input I receive. As a result, the function outputs a list of all validations that broke.

My problem is that when in one of those places I should ignore one of the validations. In this case, I have 2 approaches:

- Call the same validations from both places and pop the redundant validation result (if exists) in the place that should ignore it.
- Pass the validation consumer as an argument to the validator and ignore it inside the validator code.

I find both solutions appealing, since the first one is cleaner but more implicit IMO, and the other one, although makes code more explicit is kinda ugly.

which approach is considered better?

Comment: I would choose explicitness any day :) 
IMO the first one isn't cleaner, it adds knowledge to the validator consumer, now it has to know the validations that took place (and take decisions accordingly), instead of just checking if it's valid or not. (Although also in your second option the consumer knows what validations the validator is doing)
There isn't an "always true" answer, as always it depends on your specific use case. Maybe you can find some business-related explanation as to why those validations are different and redesign your code
If you want you can add more context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

Ideally you want Validation1 and Validation2 not to depend on each other. I would go with a composition of validation rules. ie.

```
Validation1
{
    rules = [validateX, validateY]
    Validate() {
       foreach(r in rules) { ... }
    }
}

Validation2
{
    rules = [validateX, validateZ]
    Validate() {
       foreach(r in rules) { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go for the second option, you'll have to introduce a special case (an if statement, a check) in your validation function. This may not a big deal now, or, if this is a one-off kind of project, may not be a problem at all. But, if this is going to be a longer-lived project, and if you keep on bolting on special cases in a similar fashion for new types of objects to validate, it's going to become more and more of a problem in several ways - special cases will proliferate within the body of the function (and possibly even elsewhere), and the code will become harder and harder to disentangle and maintain. To support new cases, you may end up needing to change the signature of the function more often than you'd like, which could affect all your call sites. Things will become unwieldy. Even if it's just the two cases, over time, it it's not unusual that the two validation requirements diverge more and more, even though they started off very similar to each other, so you'll eventually run into the same kinds of issues.

Now, with your option one, as you envisioned it, what will happen at the call site is this: you'll call the original validation procedure, and follow that with some logic that *explicitly* modifies the output. So, the validation logic there is not in itself that implicit (it's fairly easy to understand what's going on when you inspect the code), it's just that this particular validation is not explicitly *represented* as it's own construct in code.

That's easily fixed, though - encapsulate those couple of lines in a separate, well named validation function. This let's you treat the fact that you are reusing the old procedure as an implementation detail, which in turn lets you change the new validation procedure without touching the old one, and, if need be, replace all of the code in there, removing the call to the old one completely.

If both of your validation procedures have the same signature, you can even use them polymorphically: e.g., you can have your higher-level validation function take in a lambda that represents the actual, use-case specific validation procedure, and pass in one function, or the other.

Finally this can be a stepping stone towards what [Ewan suggests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/437968/275536); the most flexible option is to break down your validation procedure into smaller steps that can be combined together, almost like Legos. E.g., a particular validation procedure can be built from an array (or a list) of small-grained validation functions (or objects, if you're up for it) arranged to suit a particular use case.